# How to use narrow_cast from gsl

Tags: c++, gsl

I am trying to run the following code for narrowing errors from Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ book:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x1 = narrow_cast<int> (2.9);
    int x2 = narrow_cast<int> (2.0);
    char c1 = narrow_cast<char>(1066);
    char c2 = narrow_cast<char>(85);

    cout<<x1<<endl;
    cout<<x2<<endl;
    cout<<c1<<endl;
    cout<<c2<<endl;
}
```

However, I ran into the following error:

> fatal error: 'gsl/gsl' file not found

I am sure I have `gsl` library installed but don't know what I am doing wrong here.
I am using MAC OS and VS Code.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you compile your code? What command or Makefile do you use?

Comment: @Jules I use GCC compiler g++

Comment: I mean what is the whole command, I think that you might have forgot to include the library in the command.

Comment: @Jules I tried with `g++ -Wall -std=c++14 narr.cc -I/usr/local/include` and `g++ -Wall -std=c++14 narr.cc -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas` to include the library but no luck.

Comment: Where is your gsl directory? It needs to be in your include path.

Comment: @Ben I can see it there, in `/usr/local/include/gsl` isn't this the correct path?

Comment: That sounds correct. You are saying you have a file named `usr/local/include/gsl/gsl` (with no extension)? I’m not sure why it wouldn’t find it.

Comment: @Ben Actually I did not find another directory inside `gsl` with the same name as you stated with `usr/local/include/gsl/gsl` it is just `/usr/local/include/gsl` and the files inside this directory are the header files only (with `.h` extension).

Comment: @Ben I tried also with `#include <gsl>` but same issue.

Comment: The include directive needs a *file* name. If you have `/usr/local/include/gsl/gsl/gsl.h` then you want `/usr/local/include/gsl` in your path and then `#include <gsl/gsl.h>`.

Comment: @Ben I see. I guess the problem is because `gsl.h` file is missing as I did not find it in `gsl` directory. And if I included other files e.g., `#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>` I don't get that error.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like at least the Microsoft GSL implementation doesn’t have extensions, so the includes are `<gsl/span>` for example. https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/tests/span_tests.cpp They do provide `<gsl/gsl>` as a header that includes everything.